# tez buil error - shufflehandler

Tags: cloudera-cdh, tez

I am installing Tez-0.8.4 based on Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.10.0.
I got this error. Please help me when I tried to build Tez source with maven .

> /apache-tez-0.8.4-src/tez-ext-service-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/tez/shufflehandler/ShuffleHandler.java:[370,18] cannot find symbol
>   [ERROR] symbol:   method getHeader(java.lang.String)
>   [ERROR] location: variable request of type org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this answer from my coworker
we have to use "headers().set, headers().get" instead of "setHeader(), getHeader()".